# Scilab, spline interpolation, fsolve

Tags: spline, scilab

Can I do something like **[this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13319263/matlab-spline-interpolation-find-x-from-y)** in Scilab? By fsolve(...)?

I think that's necessary to add some things to improve the question.

I have a function defined as follows:

```
function f=equ(x)
    f=y-((-0.0235037+39.432867*x)/(1+83.598972*x-43.946883*x.^2));
endfunction
```

and then this:

```
i=1;
xp(1)=xD;
yp(1)=xD;
y=xD;
while (xp(i)>xi),
    xp(i+1)=fsolve(0.01,equ);
    yp(i+1)=R/(R+1)*xp(i+1)+xD/(R+1);
    y=yp(i+1);
    plot([xp(i),xp(i+1)],[yp(i),yp(i)],"r");
    if (xp(i+1)>xi) plot([xp(i+1),xp(i+1)],[yp(i),yp(i+1)],"r");
    end
        i=i+1;
end
```

I would like to change the function with a spline fit:

```
xx=linspace(0,1,100)';
yy2=interp1(x,y,xx,"spline");
```

in which x, y are experimental data (x=[...], y=[...]), or:

```
xx=linspace(0,1,100)';
df=splin(x,y,"monotone");
[yyf,yy1f,yy2f]=interp(xx,x,y,df);
```

Can I apply fsolve to a spline fit? Or it's necessary to do something else? Thanks.

Comment: I'm not exactly sure what you are looking for, maybe [the following site](http://libflow.com/d/firowmv1/Polynomial_Interpolation_in_Scilab) can help you.

Comment: The data are not fitted by a polynomial model. A possibility is given by a rational model, as I posted in the code. But the spline is the best. My question is about the use in Scilab of something like this: `fzero(@(xi)interp1(x,y,xi,'spline'),5)`

Answer (score 0):

Something like [this](http://help.scilab.org/docs/5.3.1/en_US/splin.html)? Using splin?

```
x  = [2,3,4,5,6]; 
y  = [10,8,4,1,-2]; 
xi = linspace(2,6,100);

yk = interp(xi, x, y, splin(x,y,"not_a_knot"));
yf = interp(xi, x, y, splin(x,y,"fast"));
ym = interp(xi, x, y, splin(x,y,"monotone"));

plot(x,y,'o',xi,yk,'-') 
plot(x,y,'X',xi,yf,'-r') 
plot(x,y,'+',xi,yf,'-b') 

xlabel('x')
ylabel('y') 
legend(['','Not a knot','','Fast','','Monotone'])
```